# Varnish Security

Tags: security, varnish

Varnish security **main.vcl** contains

```
# clear all internal variables
include "/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl";
```

and

```
# fallthrough: clear all internal variables on security.vcl_recv exit
include "/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl";
```

but **/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl** is not included into the git. 
I commented it out, and it is working fine but where can I get **/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl**? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a script in the tools directory to build it?

http://git.varnish-cache.org/old/varnish/varnish-tools/security.vcl/tools/generate_variables